# I am trying to add two float arrays into a third array but receive only zeros

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I want to use 3 looping structures for three different arrays. The first loop generates numbers 0 to 49. The second loop takes the first loop numbers and squares them. The third loop holds the sum of all 49 values.

If I put it all in a single statement, I get exactly what I want, except it doesn't fill each array:

```java
System.out.println(value[i] + "\t" + Math.pow(value[i], 2) + "\t" + (value[i] + Math.pow(value[i], 2)));
```

I'm having troubles with the code. After using print statements, I can see the first loop working, however it isn't filling the second loop which is resulting in all zeros.

```java
int loopMax = 49;
value = new float [50];
valueSQ = new float [50];
sum = new float [value.length + valueSQ.length];

for (i = 0; i < loopMax; i++)
{
    value[i] = i + 1;
}

/*Results in 49 zeros*/
for (j = 0; j < loopMax; j++)
{
    valueSQ[j] = (float) Math.pow(value[i], 2);
    //System.out.println (valueSQ[j]);
}

/*Results in all zeros*/
for (k = 0; k < loopMax; k++)
{
    sum[k] = valueSQ[j] + value[i];
    System.out.println (sum[k]);
}
```

This is my base code. I figured the zeros were because I wasn't filling the second array properly. I tried creating new arrays since I can't change the old arrays but it hasn't helped. Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong or why I'm getting all zeros after the first loop?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you start declaring local variables at the point of first use. So your for loops would be (for example) `for (int i = 0; i < loopMax; i++)` and your array initializers would be `float[] value = new float[50];` etc. By keeping your scope minimized, you avoid bugs like this where you're using the wrong variable.

Comment: Rule of thumb: always declare your variables as late as possible. That is, exactly as Jon Skeet says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sum[k] = valueSQ[j] + value[i];
```

The values j and i are not what you need them to be.

Change the above line in:

```
sum[k] = valueSQ[k] + value[k];
```

EDIT: as @SagunDevkota already stated, in your second loop,

change:

```
valueSQ[j] = (float) Math.pow(value[i], 2);
```

to

```
valueSQ[j] = (float) Math.pow(value[j], 2);
```

The reason for this is because i is not reset for the second loop, nor will it augment, the way j will.

You should consider i to be out of scope for the second and third loop, and j for the third loop.

As @JonSkeet remarked, it is better to declare the variable where you need them in such cases:

```
        for (i = 0; i < loopMax; i++)     {
            value[i] = i + 1;
        }
        
        for (j = 0; j < loopMax; j++){
            valueSQ[j] = (float) Math.pow(value[i], 2);
        }
```

This shows us that both i and j are declared as instance variables, static variables, or earlier in the method this code is from.

If you remove those variables, and re-write the code like this:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < loopMax; i++)     {
            value[i] = i + 1;
        }
        
        for (int j = 0; j < loopMax; j++){
            valueSQ[j] = (float) Math.pow(value[i], 2);
        }
```

When you try to compile this, the compiler will tell you that you are using i out of it's scope. The variable i only exists within the scope of the first loop, so the code for the second loop would not compile.

Comment: It may be worth noting that if the loop variables had been declared in the for loops themselves, this bug would have been prevented because `j` and `i` wouldn't have been in scope.

Comment: indeed. the op seems to be new to the concept of scopes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the explanation! Firstly, I did declare instance variables of type int for i, j, and k at the start. I just forgot to include them! Secondly, I was alittle confused as to why the integers for each loop can't carry over into another loop. For example: valueSQ[j] = (float) Math.pow(value[i], 2); Seemed logical to me because it was the integer "i" that I wanted to square so that's why I put it in the next loop. Putting the int "j" there is what made it work and I am still confused why. I need to do more learning! Thanks for your time everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Change value[i] to value[j] in second loop

```
valueSQ[j] = (float) Math.pow(value[j], 2);
```

Change valueSQ[j] to valueSQ[k] and value[i] to value[k] in third loop

```
sum[k] = valueSQ[k] + value[k];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'm not really in a position to "suggest" anything but, a short explanation of why this was the answer would have been great as I'm really interested in learning. BUT regardless, your answer and your time are greatly appreciated!

Comment: The value of `i` in second loop will be 49 according to your logic. Which will not alter value in any position of the array. You will have to manually re assign value of i to 0 `i = 0;` before second loop and increment i by 1 `i++;` for every iteration. And, value of i,j to 0 `i = 0; j = 0;` before the third loop and increment i and j `i++; j++;` which is not a preferable way. As mentioned by @Stultuske you need to learn about scopes for more information

Comment: Noted! Thank you for that explanation! And now instead of a general search of information, I can now look into "scopes" specifically. Much appreciated!